# Seem to have trouble merging folders on my hard drive

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to maintain a master copy of my files. I want this master copy to be on my external hard drive.

So for example,

at Time 1: I have file A on my laptop, nothing on my hard drive. I perform a file transfer and now I have file A on my hard drive, nothing on my laptop.

at Time 2: I have file B on my laptop, A on my hard drive. I perform a file transfer and now I have files A and B on my hard drive, nothing on my laptop.

However, I don't want to specify that I want to move over only files A or B. Similarly, I don't want to overwrite the folder containing B with the folder containing A.

**Think of this like a git repository for my laptop hard drive.**

There is an option on my mac to `merge' two folders. However, when I try merging the existing root folder I have on my laptop with the one on my drive, I get a error[0] code on my mac.

I already formatted it to OS Extended, Journalled format so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this message.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Why not just use Time Machine, that's its job?

Comment: +1 for this. It works really well and will take versions of your files, not only back them up for you.

Comment: Time machine just takes snap shots of your drive and can restore your drive from those snapshots right, not create one mega union of all your drive snapshots

Comment: Time Machine is an incremental system, using hard links as placeholders so they take no space. It will do this with no detailed user input at all You can restore any or all files, inc system, from any specific day as far back in time as the partition can hold. Mine currently stores about a year, backing a 1TB drive to a 3TB TM. If you want longer archiving, swap out the TM drive when it starts deleting older backups. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgbrn.png

Comment: I have updated my question - I think Time Machine only captures snapshots of the HDD at that moment. I want a union across all time of these snapshots. Does Time Machine give you that?